Is it safe to put LiFePO4 in the server rack?
They make rack mounted LiFePO4 units like the 48V 100Ah Cloudenergy Store. Is it safe to put these units in the same rack with the server? Should they go to the bottom or the top? Are there any other safety concerns I should evaluate before purchasing one?

Safe is relative. It's safer not to have them in your rack if you don't need emergency power. You have to weigh the risks.

Regardless of the technology used, it is always safer to use a separate compartment in a completely different room rather than using the same space. I agree with vidarli.
The real Point of view you should be considering yourself is:

How safe does it need to be?
How much are you willing to pay for it?

So there will be no clear yes or no Answer for this Question. It always and will depend on the requirements and availability of the location as also available rooms
